# AngularJS Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined occurs when adding an item to an array

Tags: angularjs, http, post, http-post

When running a function that adds a new item to an array:

```
$scope.accounts.push(responce);
```

(the array that has a search filter, yes/no filter and is ordered.)

```
ng-repeat="x in accounts | searchFilter:searchString | enabledFilter:isEnabled | orderBy: ['-favourite','account'] as results"
```

Once a new item is added, this error occurs **Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined** when using the filters.

Note: After a refresh of the page, it will work again.

Comment: clearly something is undefined, and the code tried to lowercase it as if it were a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, change the code to this:

```
if (responce !== undefined) $scope.accounts.push(responce);
```

This will prevent undefined values from being added to the array which should fix the error you were getting with the filter.

Comment: The response is an JS object, that will have one null value, but this value will not be filtered. The three values that are filtered are strings, that are either empty strings or hold values.
Eg.
`{"id":"363","account":"a4","serverLocation":"","comment":"","securityLevel":"2","added":"19/08/2016 10:21:23 AM","updated":"19/08/2016 10:21:23 AM","enabled":"true","favourite":null}`

Comment: Doesn't work, as the returned object is not undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've found that the object is not in a correct format and is causing the error.